# Code inside function not working as it should

Tags: python

I have a very simple task I want to run from within a function.

```
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='DUMMY')
    objDup = bpy.context.scene.objects.active    
    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
```

Now when I run this as is, outside the function, everything's ok. It does what it's supposed to, takes the active object, duplicates it, the duplicate is automatically made an active object, so it defines that in a variable and removes all its shapekeys.

But when I run it inside the function mainFunction, it duplicates the active object, but removes the shapekeys from the original instead of the duplicated object, although the code is very clear about it... What gives???

Here's the code:

```
import bpy

    class FreezeShapes(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_label = "Freeze ShapeKeys"
        bl_idname = "obj.frzshps"   
        def execute(self, context):
            #Check the type and the number of the objects:
            Actobj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
            if Actobj.type == "MESH":
                shpKys = Actobj.data.shape_keys
                if shpKys is not None:
                    ob = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
                    self.mainFunction(ob)
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass 
            return {'FINISHED'}

        def mainFunction(self, obj):
            obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active               
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='DUMMY')
            objDup = bpy.context.scene.objects.active    
            bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True)
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj    
            return {'FINISHED'}

    ###########################################################################

    class AJ_SHAPEKEY_UTILS_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
        """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
        bl_label = "AJ_SHAPEKEY_UTILS"
        bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
        bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
        bl_context = "data" 

        def draw(self, context):
             layout = self.layout
             scn = bpy.context.scene
             row.operator(FreezeShapes.bl_idname, icon='FREEZE')

    ###########################################################################

    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(FreezeShapes)
        bpy.utils.register_class(AJ_SHAPEKEY_UTILS_Panel)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        register()
```

Select an object with shapekeys, run it; then go to the data tab and in the custom menu at the very bottom, press "Freeze ShapeKeys"...

I must be doing something wrong here, no?

Thanx for all the replies in advance;

AJ

Comment: When posting code on this site, please make it be as short as possible; a.k.a. remove all the unnecessary parts.

Comment: It's would appear to be a context issue, if you change your panel to `bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D" and bl_region_type = "UI"` so it shows in the properties sidebar it works as you want.